# Configure the user's default choice on tinyMCE toolbar

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

I am using v5 of TinyMCE. By default, the style selected is 'Paragraph', as shown in this image :
[[tinyMCE toolbar, as the user sees before he mades any format configuration]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNjuf.png)

But I know my users will all prefer to use 'Div' style. So I would like 'Div' to be selected by default. The toolbar should therefore appear like in this image :
[[tinyMCE toolbar, as I want it to be configured by default]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EW5X.png)

Is it possible ?
I haven't find my answer in [tinyMCE documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/quick-start/).
Same question if you want for instead "bold" button to be selected by default, etc.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace the default `<p>` blocks with `<div>`, use forced_root_block: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/reference/Configuration3x/Configuration3x@forced_root_block/

```
tinymce.init({
  // ...
  forced_root_block : 'div'
});
```

To select the bold button by default, you could use `execCommand`: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#execcommand

```
tinymce.init({
    // ...
    setup: function(editor) {
      editor.on('init', function() {
          this.execCommand('Bold');
      });
    }
});
```

Example fiddle combining both: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/YShaab/1